# Time complexity of nested while loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity, big-o

I am stumped on how to determine the time complexity for the while loop in this statement:

```
procedure P (integer n);
 for (i: 1 to n)
   x := n;
   while (x > 0)
         x := x - i;
```

I know that the for loop runs (n-1) times. At first I thought that the while loop would run n times because I mistook the i for a 1 but that is not the case. I have been inputting numbers to see when the program would stop, but do not see a consistent pattern. I noticed that as n increases, the while loop runs longer (but not by much) so could this be logarithmic somewhat? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first run makes n while-cycles
The second run makes n/2 while-cycles
The third run makes n/3 while-cycles
k-th run makes n/k while cycles

So overall time is proportional to

```
n * (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 +...+1/n)
```

In the brackets we can see partial sum of [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), that tends to natural logarithm of n, and complexity is O(n log n)

Answer (score 0):

MBo answer is well detailed.
If you got so far, maybe you are asking yourselves, why for the first run there are n while-cycles, second run n/2 while-cycles, etc.

```
     x := n;
     while (x > 0)
         x := x - i;
```

All cycles run until `x==0` by the condition of the while loop

therefore the first while-cycle run: `n-t*1=0` times for some integer `t` and `i==1`

the second while-cycle run: `n-t*2=0` times for some integer `t` and `i==1`

So we get for the first one `n=t` for the second `n=2t`so `n/2=t` third `n/3=t`